# Change Tabulator Tree Icon

Tags: tabulator

Firstly, love the product!

Secondly, is it possible to change the expand and collapse icons for tree module within Tabulator? It would really help with the consistency of my project if I were to instead use the block arrows (Alt 16 & Alt 30).

I've already manipulated the CSS to the remove the border, etc.

The data and columns are substituted within the software package I am compiling this within.

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    height:400,
    data: [ **TableData** ]
    dataTree:true,
    dataTreeStartExpanded:true,
    dataTreeBranchElement: false,
    dataTreeChildIndent: 9,
    dataTreeCollapseElement: !1,
    dataTreeStartExpanded: !1,
    layout:"fitColumns",
    columns:[ **ColumnData** ],
    rowClick:function(e, row){ //trigger an alert message when the row is clicked
        alert("ID " + row.getData().id + " Selected");
    },
});
```

I am pairing this with

```
<link href="dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Comment: Apologies, first time poster (obviously). I hope this above clarifies. At the moment I am running the basic example (http://tabulator.info/basic/4.2) with dataTree set to true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ***dataTreeExpandElement*** and ***dataTreeCollapseElement*** setup options for this in your table constructor

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    dataTree:true,
    dataTreeCollapseElement:"<span>►</span>",
    dataTreeExpandElement:"<span>▼</span>",
});
```

Full details on how to use this feature can be found in the [Data Tree Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/tree#layout-colexp)

Answer (score 1):

Checking the source code for Tabulator, dataTreeCollapseElement and dataTreeExpandElement are either looking for a string or DOM element.  Try specifying an empty element that won't show:

```
dataTreeCollapseElement: '<i/>',
dataTreeExpandElement: '<i/>',
```